# php - Could not connect to the server

Tags: php, mysql

help ! i keep on getting this error when calling a routin on the mysql database. all the other commands on my php file that connects to the database are all working. it's only on this routine that gives this error . anyone who can help me ?
[image]

the code for the routine is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsServiceRepair`(IN `requestID` CHAR(10), IN `requestDate` DATETIME, IN `requestorID` CHAR(10), IN `repairDescription` VARCHAR(100), IN `letterAddress` VARCHAR(50))
NO SQL
begin

insert into Service values
(requestID, requestDate, requestorID, 0);

insert into `Repair` values
(requestID, repairDescription, letterAddress);
end
```

thank you!

Comment: Are Service and Repair tables 3 columns only?

Comment: @mihai 4 columns for service, and 3 columns for repair . actually repair is a subtype of service.

Comment: If other mysql commands work then it is probably able to contact the server. Your error message is misleading. Where your application is making mysql calls and checking that it was successful, output the result of mysql_error(). This will help you find out what is wrong with your routine.

Comment: Also NO SQL means the procedure contains no sql statements.Isn't insert a sql statement..